# SQL view for acquaintance from table

Tags: sql

I have a table for friends

```
PLAYER_ID    FRIEND_ID
----------------------
1            2
1            3         // 1 knows 3
3            1         // 3 knows 1
2            4
```

How can I create a view containing those acquaintances(know each other) for given player?

```
PLAYER_ID    FRIEND_ID
----------------------
1            3
3            1
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the needed select:

```
select t1.PLAYER_id, t1.FRIEND_ID from tablename t1
inner join tablename t2 on t1.PLAYER_id = t2.FRIEND_ID and t2.PLAYER_id = t1.FRIEND_ID
```

Comment: Sorry, the site allowed me after 6 minutes.

Comment: @JinKwon no problem :) don't forget the name of your son!!

Answer (score 2):

```
select p1.player_id, p1.friend_Id
from player p1 
inner join player p2 on p1.player_id = p2.friend_id and p2.player_id = p1.friend_id
```

Comment: I'll name my daughter as `Raphaël Althaus`

Comment: Dear Raphaël Althaus, I accepted aF.'s answer because he seems answered just a little bit faster than you. Thanks.